# Is there a DBus command to toggle auto-hide on a KDE Plasma panel?

Tags: linux, kde, dbus, kde-plasma-workspace

Is there a DBus command (or some other way from the command line) to toggle auto-hide on a panel in KDE Plasma?  (I'm running KDE 4.6.)

I have a game I run in WINE that doesn't work right if it's autohidden and it would be nice to run it from a script that takes care of that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily through [plasma desktop scripts](http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting), like this:

auto-hide on:

```
var panel = panelById(panelIds[0])
panel.hiding = 'autohide';
```

auto-hide off:

```
var panel = panelById(panelIds[0])
panel.hiding = 'none';
```

The bad news is there is no way to programatically [run the script](http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting#Running_Scripts) when you want it except perhaps for some kind of keyboard+mouse automation.

The closest you can get (per [this discussion on KDE forum](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=88100)) is open the script in desktop console via

```
qdbus org.kde.plasma-desktop /MainApplication \
    loadScriptInInteractiveConsole /path/to/js/file
```

There is [bug #238817](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238817) in KDE Bugzilla filed on this.

Comment: Yeah, scripting is pretty useless if you can't execute them!  Accepting for now.  (BTW, I voted for your RFE bug. :-)

Comment: Hi, the above code is not working for me. For instance, if I run ```panel.height=30```, it responds and changes accordingly. However, changing ```panel.hiding``` gives me no response.

Also, to run it programmatically, why does something like @dufferZafar's answer work?


I am running KDE Plasma 5.15.5

Answer (score 3):

As of July 2018, the answer suggested by @che doesn't work.

Here is something that does work though:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell evaluateScript "p = panelById(panelIds[0]); p.height = 32 - p.height;"
```

32 is the height I like. Set that to a different number as you like.

Relevant KDE Bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396796

Answer (score 0):

There is a kwin script that toggle panel

https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1266534/

and

https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1269113/

We can also add more feature to a panel by setting it up in (KDE System Settings - Window Manager - Window Rules - New - Detect Window Properties "And select your pannel"

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to run any script to hide the Plasma Panel.

There is a setting in System Settings that enables Full screen windows to be navigated away from, without taking the window out of Full Screen mode.

In System Settings → Work Space Behaviour → Screen Edges there are three check boxes at the top of the screen

Maximise Windows dragged to top edge

Tile Windows dragged to left or Right Edge

**Behaviour: Remain Active when Windows are Full Screen**

This last one when checked seems to allow Windows to be Full screen (which is what I want for my VM Windows) with the ability to switch to other desktops when desired. So this will work for any case where you require the Panel be hidden, but also wish to navigate to other workspaces.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check [Re: Documentation for the dbus methods for plasma](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=86855&p=153207&hilit=dbus#p153207) and for some example of how to use dbus [Lauching K menu with DBus](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=8738).

If a method is present it will easy to find.

Comment: I've been looking through qdbusviewer properties of krunner, kwin, and especially plasma-desktop, but there was nothing that seemed related to the Plasma panel :( There was no item for plasma itself.

Comment: Tried to chat with some kde-geek? Forum, irc and mailing list of kde project can help. That problem of no item for plasma is really odd.

Comment: I was hoping to get around this kind of research by asking the question here :-)